# how to integrate google cloud speech api to my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am new for google cloud platform. I need to integrate google speech API to my webpage using JavaScript, I searched for documentations but no luck. Can anyone knows please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sample source code and pre-requisites are given for integrating google cloud speech into your Java project at: 
[Sample source code for integrating google cloud speech APIs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-speech)

Comment: @SaiHarshita You'll have to git clone the [project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java.git). Once you've checked it out, check the source at path: (google-cloud-java/google-cloud-speech/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/speech/v1/SpeechClient.java).